# Pytorch doesn't find a CUDA device

Tags: pytorch

I tried using Cuda in Pytorch in my set up but it can't be detected and I am puzzled as to why.

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

return `False`. Digging deeper,

```
torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount()
```

returns 0. Using version 1.5, e.g.

```
$ pip freeze | grep torch
torch==1.5.0
```

I tried to write a small C program to do the same, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

int main() {
   int count = 0;
   cudaGetDeviceCount(&count);
   printf("Device count: %d\n", count);
   return 0;
}
```

prints 1, so the Cuda runtime can obviously find a device. Also, running `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   41C    P8     9W / 200W |    219MiB /  6075MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

So where did my Cuda device disappear in Python?

Answer (score 5):

I now just realized that there is a different version if Pytorch for every different minor version of CUDA, so in my case version `torch==1.5.0` defaults to CUDA 10.2 apparently, while the special package `torch==1.5.0+cu101` works.

I hope this clears things up for other people who like me start reading the docs on PyPi (more up to date docs if you know where to look are here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Comment: In addition, you could mention that if one has enough disk space and wants to use conda, pytorch comes with its own cudatoolkit package that will ensure the right cuda libraries are available in the environment ;)

Comment: I don't want Conda. I want to stick to my good old requirements.txt as I am used to :P

Comment: Actually the thing will go into a Docker image eventually. But that is step #2

Comment: So you will be using an environment technology after all... so much for _good_ _old_ ...

Comment: @Jan the pip version also comes with the "cudatoolkit package"... the problem here is that OP's nvidia driver is not compatible with cuda 10.2 (should be `>= 440.33`)

Comment: @Jan Well, before Docker there was virtualenv. Python without *some* kind of scoping is kind of torture. My very personal opionion is that tools like conda are made for/by data science people without a solid software engineering background.

Comment: And yes, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 which installs Cuda 10.1 by default.

Comment: In addition to `pip uninstal torch torchvision`, I also had to `pip cache purge` before running the cmds in the linked docs